# Wants to generate a random password on Linux server of length 15 characters

Tags: bash

String must contain at least 3 uppercase, 3 lowercase, 3 digits and at least 3 special characters.

I searched a lot, but not able to get the required solution.

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9-_' | head -c15
```

This is what I found, but I am able to get the random combination of all.
What i needed is it must output at least 3 characters from each set.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: yes I have tried using this command head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9-_' | head -c15
having underscore and hypen as special characters, but as this gives random output of all the combination, I want it to output at least 3 charcters from all combination each

Comment: @SreekanthKondaiah [edit] your question and insert your code.  People here enjoy answering questions but they don't like being treated as free consulting service.  By adding your code to the question and explaining where you got stuck, you show honest effort and that should stop the downvoters and help encourage useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LC_ALL=C
upp=$(tr -dc 'A-Z' </dev/urandom | head -c3)
low=$(tr -dc 'a-z' </dev/urandom | head -c3)
dig=$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c3)
spe=$(tr -dc '!-/' </dev/urandom | head -c3)
res=$(tr -dc '!-}' </dev/urandom | head -c3)
echo "$upp$low$dig$spe$res"
```

First, the statement `export LC_ALL=C` makes sure that we are using just plain ASCII.  This eliminates potential issues associated with unicode characters.

Next, the variable `upp` is assigned to 3 upper-case characters. Similarly, `low` gets three lower-case, `$dig` gets three digits, `spe` gets three special characters, and `res` gets 3 random characters.  The `echo` statement combines all four variables ands prints them.

The above prints the upper case characters first, lower case second, etc.  If you want this order mixed up, replace the last line above with:

```
echo "$upp$low$dig$spe$res" | sed 's/./&\n/g' | shuf | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John1024, this is working. am new to posting questions thanks for guiding me, will make sure next time onwards will add my findings in the question.

Comment: @SreekanthKondaiah Very good.  I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: the output is being constant, first upper,lower,digits,special and the rest.
so I tried using /dev/random command to the ouptut like below tr -dc "$upp$low$dig$spe$res" </dev/urandom | head -c15, but am getting this error tr: range-endpoints of '6--' are in reverse collating sequence order"after couple attempts. searched a lot but not getting the correct output.

Comment: @SreekanthKondaiah See updated answer for a method, using the utility `shuf`, to shuffle the character order.

Comment: Thank very much @John1024 this worked, I looking for some books to learn sed utility not sure which one to chose, can you suggest me some good references.

Comment: @SreekanthKondaiah Glad it worked. As for tutorials, it's a bit old but I like the simplicity and clarity of the explanations in the [Grymoire SED tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  There are, however, lots of good tutorials; just pick one that matches your learning style.

Answer (score 0):

This script uses [openssl-rand](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-rand.html) to get strings of 15 letters/numbers/special characters until the loop breaks when all conditions are met and the password is printed.

```
#!/bin/bash

until [ -z "$pw+x" ]
do
  pw=$(openssl rand -base64 32 | cut -c1-15) &&\
  [[ $(sed "s/[^[:upper:]]//g" <<< $pw | wc -c) -gt 3 ]] &&\
  [[ $(sed "s/[^[:lower:]]//g" <<< $pw | wc -c) -gt 3 ]] &&\
  [[ $(sed "s/[^0-9]//g" <<< $pw | wc -c) -gt 3 ]] &&\
  [[ $(sed "s/[[:alnum:]]//g" <<< $pw | wc -c) -gt 3 ]] && break
done

echo "$pw"
```